# After reading urls from a text file, how can I save all the responses into separate files?

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-post

I have a script that reads urls from a text file, performs a request and then saves all the responses in one text file. How can I save each response in a different text file instead of all in the same file? For example, if my text file labeled input.txt has 20 urls, I would like to save the responses in 20 different .txt files like output1.txt, output2.txt instead of just one .txt file. So for each request, the response in saved in a new .txt file. Thank you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue

        response = requests.get(line)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        categories = soup.find_all("a", {"class":'navlabellink nvoffset nnormal'})

        for category in categories:
            data = line + "," + category.text

            with open('output.txt', 'a+') as f:
                f.write(data + "\n")
                print(data)
```

Comment: Your indents are wrong? This would only use the last line in the file

Comment: @MZ Hi thank you, can you specify which indents? This code runs fine when I build it

Comment: Everything with your response should be indented inside `for line in map(str.strip, f_in):`?

Comment: @MZ Thanks, it was an error during creating the listing. Fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to implement what others have hinted at:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for i, line in enumerate(map(str.strip, f_in)):
        if not line:
            continue

        ...

            with open(f'output_{i}.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(data + "\n")
                print(data)
```

Comment: The caveat of doing it this way is there's no way to programmatically map the same URL to a file later. By using a hashing function instead, as long as you have the same link you can get the filename at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new file by using `open('something.txt', 'w')`. If the file is found, it'll erase its content. Else, it'll make a new file named 'something.txt'. Now, you can use `file.write()` to write your info!

Comment: So if I have 20 urls in a .txt file, I have to write open('something.txt', 'w') 20 different ways?

Comment: Yes, that is to open it. But make sure that if you use `open()` you have to use `file.close()` once you're done. If you don't, the file will stay open and it may cause problems.

Comment: The OP is using the with builtin [context manage](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)r so the file doesn't need to be closed explicitly. It's automatically closed after the with block is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if I understood your problem right.

I would create an array/list and would create an object for each url request and response. Then add the objects to the array/list and write for each object a different file.

Comment: For example, if my text file labeled input.txt has 20 urls, I would like to save the responses in 20 different .txt files like output1.txt, output2.txt instead of just one .txt file. So for each request, the response in saved in a new .txt file.

Comment: You also could read the input.txt line for line. 
E.g.:

f = open("input.txt", "r")

for x in f:
    input = open("input" + x + ".txt", "w")
    line = f.readline()
    input.write(line)
    input.close()

Don't know if this code is correct, but you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways you could generate files for each url. One, shown below, is to create a hash of some data unique data of the file. In this case I chose category but your could also use the whole contents of the file. This creates a unique string to use for a file name so that two links with the same category text don't overwrite each other when saved.

Another way, not shown, is to find some unique value within the data itself and use it as the filename without hashing it. However, this can cause more problems than it solves since data on the Internet should not be trusted.

Here's your code with an MD5 hash used for a filename. [MD5 is not a secure hashing function](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-has-been-cracked-since-1996) for passwords but it's safe for creating unique filenames.

### Updated Snippet

```py
import hashlib

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue

    response = requests.get(line)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    categories = soup.find_all("a", {"class":'navlabellink nvoffset nnormal'})

    for category in categories:
        data = line + "," + category.text
        filename = hashlib.sha256()
        filename.update(category.text.encode('utf-8'))
        with open('{}.html'.format(filename.hexdigest()), 'w') as f:
            f.write(data + "\n")
            print(data)
```

### Code added

```py
filename = hashlib.sha256()
filename.update(category.text.encode('utf-8'))
with open('{}.html'.format(filename.hexdigest()), 'w') as f:
```

### Capturing Updated Pages

If you care about catching contents of a page at different points in time, hash the whole contents of the file. That way, if anything within the page changes the previous contents of the page aren't lost. In this case, I hash both the url and the file contents and concatenate the hashes with the URL hash followed by a hash of the file contents. That way, all versions of a file are visible when the directory is sorted.

```py
hashed_contents = hashlib.sha256()
hashed_contents.update(category['href'].encode('utf-8'))
with open('{}.html'.format(filename.hexdigest()), 'w') as f:

for category in categories:
        data = line + "," + category.text
        hashed_url = hashlib.sha256()
        hashed_url.update(category['href'].encode('utf-8'))
        page = requests.get(category['href'])
        hashed_content = hashlib.sha256()
        hashed_content.update(page.text.encode('utf-8')
        filename = '{}_{}.html'.format(hashed_url.hexdigest(), hashed_content.hexdigest())
        with open('{}.html'.format(filename.hexdigest()), 'w') as f:
            f.write(data + "\n")
            print(data)
```